# Sending Json Request returns invalid error using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to post json data to an Api using PHP but it returns error of an invalid data. Below is the Json request format

My Json request

```
{
  "Detail": {
    "ServiceRequestVersion": "1.0",
    "Token": "my token goes here",
  },
  "CustomerInformation": {
    "ProductVerID": "706",
    "ProductID": "619",
    "List": [
      {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I guess that my issue is how I am trying to send the request by passing the request in the array below

```
$data_string = array(
"Detail[0].ServiceRequestVersion" => "1.0",
"Detail[0].Token => "my token goes Here",

 "CustomerInformation[0].ProductVerID" => "709",
 "CustomerInformation[0].ProductID" => "200",
 "List[0].[FirstName]" => "John",
 "List[0].[LastName]" => "Mark"

);
```

Here is the entire code. Can someone help me fix the code:

```
<?php


$data_string = array(
"Detail[0].ServiceRequestVersion" => "1.0",
"Detail[0].Token => "my token goes Here",

 "CustomerInformation[0].ProductVerID" => "709",
 "CustomerInformation[0].ProductID" => "200",
 "List[0].[FirstName]" => "John",
 "List[0].[LastName]" => "Mark"

); 

$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "my api goes here", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: my auth goes here", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$result = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);



if($result === false) {

 echo "data failed to be posted";
echo $result;
}

 else {
'Data successfully created';
}





if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
echo $result; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is not how you use `json_encode`. Someone will provide a clean example shortly! Don't fret. Its a simple fix. Side note: your example code provided is missing a `"` in there which is breaking all the color coding. I assume your actual code has that, or you would be getting a php fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you're just creating an array or object. A PHP array, just like any other PHP array. json_encode then translates that array into JSON syntax, literally mapping the PHP properties to JSON properties. The property names in the array are not used for anything except as literal names, which is what they are. They are not used to control the structure in any way. I'm not sure where you got the idea for the bizarre syntax in your question from.

Declare your array just as you would if you wanted the same data structure in PHP.

This will generate the correct structure:

```
$data_string = array(
  "Detail" => array(
    "ServiceRequestVersion" => "1.0",
    "Token" => "my token goes Here"
  ),
  "CustomerInformation" => array(
    "ProductVerID" => "709",
    "ProductID" => "200",
    "List" => array( 
      0 => array(
        "FirstName" => "John",
        "LastName" => "Mark"
      )
    )
  ),
);
```

See https://eval.in/1035515 for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your $data_string by the below code and then check:

```
    $data_string = array(
      "Detail" => array(
        "ServiceRequestVersion" => "1.0",
        "Token" => "my token goes Here"
      ),
      "CustomerInformation" => array(
        "ProductVerID" => "709",
        "ProductID" => "200",
      ),
      "List" => array(
        "FirstName" => "John",
        "LastName" => "Mark"
      )
    );
```

Comment: Not quite right: see https://eval.in/1035511, there are a few differences compared to OP's required structure

Comment: Sir Kunal, i have tried your solution but is not working yet. now the code does not show any error. Nothing is submitted. Am thinking the issue is the List Array not properly inserted. The list array seems to have {[ ---]} "FirstName[0]" => "John". please can you help me further. between thank you so far

Comment: Sir ADyson, I have tested yours but it seem you are omitting [ ]  in the submitted arrays. I think that is what makes my code not working. please how do I add that [ ] to the firstname and lastname variable